# Mounting with sshfs doesn't work after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: sshfs, osx-yosemite

This afternoon I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite and attempted to mount a catalog in a server using sshfs (that I had installed using homebrew). This worked flawlessly before the upgrade. However after the upgrade I got an error regarding not being able to run unsigned kexts - I ran the following command to circumvent that issue:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

And it seemed to fix the issue. But then I kept getting two other errors:

> remote host has disconnected

and

> failed to mount PATH: Socket is not connected

My console has the following to say about it:

> 614 KernelEventAgent[66]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_DEAD (32)

Any idea what gives? I've tried upgrading homebrew and then checking for updates, but there were none for sshfs. I also tried uninstalling sshfs and then installing it again to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am using OSXFUSE 2.7.1 from OSXFUSE website on Yosemite without any notable issue. Did you try `brew doctor`?

Comment: I did just now - got warnings about updating, unbrewed dylibs and .la - files (libfuse4x.2 among others). I removed them and then pruned the dylibs, got no more warnings, but the mounting still gives me the "remote host disconnected"- error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Solved" it, it worked if I tried connecting to the IP adress of the server rather than the DNS.. still have no clue what the problem actually is, but at least now I can work :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I have a feeling this has saved me quite a bit of time!